# How to implement HMAC in react native for ios?

Tags: javascript, ios, json, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to call API in react native using HMAC Security but I am not getting how to implement it. Please check following code which I am using to call API

```
_onPostAPICall = () => {    
 console.log("call Post api");    
 this.setState({ isLoading: true });    

 var dateFormat = require('dateformat');    
 var now = new Date();    

 console.log("Date:",dateFormat(now, "yyyymmdd HH:MM:ss"));   

 fetch('APIlink', {   

    method: "Post",   

    body: "JSON.stringify(Parameters)",   

    headers: {    
      'Accept': 'application/json',    
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',    
      'ContentDate' : dateFormat(now, "yyyymmdd HH:MM:ss"),    
    },   
  })    
  .then(response => response.json())      

  .then(json => this._handlePostAPIResponse(json))     

  .catch(error =>     
    this.setState({      
      isLoading: false,     
      message: 'Something bad happened ' + error      
   }));      
 };
```

I have googled about it.but found no clue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you found anything yet?

Comment: yes.I have found solution to the above issue.I have used crypto-js to do HMAC security.